# Azure Data Factory Retrieve the status of ForEach Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]
[image]

In Azure Data Factory is it possible to retrieve the status (Succeeded, Failed etc) of a ForEach activity (that iterated over numerous items). We would like to store the status of ForEach in the OnComplete of ForEach in a stored procedure call. When we try to access activity outputs ForEach activity is not available.

Comment: Foreach activity is just a loop it only iterates the items. It does not give any output because of it we can't get foreach activity in activity output outside of it.

Comment: We are trying to get the status of the foreach activity (overall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure Data Factory Retrieve the status of ForEach Activity.

**[Foreach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) is just a loop it only iterates the items. It does not give any output because of it we can't get foreach activity in activity output outside of it.**

[image]

The only work around to your requirement is to set different set variables for `On success` and `on failure` of foreach activity as below:

[image]

> We are trying to get the status of the foreach activity (overall).

As we know ForEach activity fails when the inner activity fails for a single time so based on that we can create logic below.

- create append variable activity and get the status from the copy activity for each run with expression `@activity('Copy data1').output.executionDetails[0].status`
  [image]
- After this create a set variable outside of the foreach activity and set the value **Failed** if **Failed** is present in `activitystatus` array otherwise **Succeed** with expression `@if(contains(variables('activitystatus'),'Failed'),'Failed','Succeed')`
  [image]